# Why are "tel:" links removed in sanitization, and how to allow them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails [sanitize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize) helper to clean up input text from users, that may be formatted as markdown.

I noticed that the method strips down `tel:` links, and I wonder why, and how can I allow them.

```
>> sanitize("<a href='http://123'>click</a>")
=> "<a href=\"http://123\">click</a>"
>> sanitize("<a href='tel:123'>click</a>")
=> "<a>click</a>"
```

Of course, I have tried figuring it out from the page linked above, but was unable to. I would prefer to avoid writing a "scrubber" class, or any other class for that simple task.

I have also tried what I think means "allow all hrefs" but it did not have any effect (even after restarting the server).

```
# In config/application.rb
config.action_view.sanitized_allowed_attributes = ['href']
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Rails 4, [Loofah](https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah) is being used for sanitizing HTML. To know more please visit [this](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2014/07/the-new-html-sanitizer-in-rails-4-2/) link.

Rails team extracted this feature into separate [gem](https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer).

If you check [this](https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer/blob/master/lib/rails/html/scrubbers.rb#L143) line, `Loofah::HTML5::WhiteList::ALLOWED_PROTOCOLS` doesnt have `tel` in their list, thus it is being striped off from anchor tags.

**Solution:**

1. Create an initializer that would add `tel` to above set of protocols.

   Loofah::HTML5::WhiteList::ALLOWED_PROTOCOLS.add('tel')
2. Restart app and this should work.

Comment: I was hoping for such a great and simple answer, so thanks a lot. Going to try that right away. Am I wrong to think that "tel:" links should be allowed by default? I mean whats the harm in that?

Comment: @DannyB yeah `tel:` links should be allowed by default I guess. May be you can open this issue in `rails-html-sanitizer` gem and ask them reason why `tel:` is not in the list by default. :)

Comment: Opened [issue #52](https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer/issues/52) - hope they will implement.